# Response from System.Net.HttpClient

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I try to make a post request using. code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

// This is the postdata
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username:", "1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password:", "1"));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

client.PostAsync("http://libdiary.liberty-lab.ru/api/v1/login", content).ContinueWith(
    (postTask) =>
    {
        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    });
```

But I do not know where the return value is transmitted from the server. Do not tell me how you can get?

Comment: The result is available in `postTask.Result`. It is an [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx).

Comment: Well, thank you! Tell me, please, how to get there, to work with him.

Comment: Or maybe you can get something like a message from the server as a string? If you tell me how to do it, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Did you check the link I posted? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it by looking at [`HttpResponseMessage.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public async Task<string> PostRequestAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username:", "1"));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password:", "1"));

    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                                   "http://libdiary.liberty-lab.ru/api/v1/login",
                                   content);

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But is there another solution? I work in the 2010 vs and there's no such things as: await,async...

Comment: Instead of using `await` you could attach a continuation to `ReadAsStringAsync` but that would be very verbose. Perhaps you should try a synchronous API?

Comment: And how it can be used immediately, do not tell me?

Comment: @ИванВеселов: it cannot be used "immediately" because it does not exist "immediately". It doesn't exist until the task which produces it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
var responseContent = await client.PostAsync(url, contentPost)
            .ContinueWith(postTask => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
            .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```